# Having problem with convert XML to XLSX and download it in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, express

My problem is that i have to create Converter and this converter takes the XML files and converts it to XLSX and download it. i was able to do the first part where the XML convert to JSON, but i have difficult to do the rest of the code, now i am trying to take the file JSON and convert it to XLSX but my code is not working, i do not know why ?

---

ControllerXML2Json.js

---

```
const { json } = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

let jsonString

async function xml2json() {
    try {
        const xml = fs.readFileSync('src/data/dataset.xml')
        const result = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(xml, { mergeAttrs: true })
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
        //console.log(json)
        fs.writeFileSync('./public/data/result.json', jsonString)
        //return jsonString
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    convert(req, res) {
        let xmlFile = req.files.fileXML

        xmlFile.mv('src/data/dataset.xml', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err)
            } else {
                xml2json()
            }
        })

    res.redirect('/json')
}
```

}

---

ControllerJson2Xlsx.js

```
const { json } = require("body-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const xlsx = require("json-as-xlsx");
const path  = require('path');
const fileName = "data.xlsx";

async function generateExcelFromJSON(){
    try {
     let content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data/result.json", "utf-8"));
      let newWS = xlsx.utils.book_new();
      let newWB = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(content);
      xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB, newWS, "data");
 
      await xlsx.writeFile("./public/data/data.xlsx", content);
     // xlsx.writeFile(newWB, "./public/data/data.xlsx");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
  download(req, res) {
    let jsonFile = req.files.fileJSON;

    jsonFile.mv('./data/data.xlsx', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
    xlsx();
      }
    });
    res.redirect("/xlsx");
  },
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that i have to create Converter and this converter takes the XML files and converts it to XLSX and download it. i was able to do the first part where the XML convert to JSON, but i have difficult to do the rest of the code, now i am trying to take the file JSON and convert it to XLSX but my code is not working, i do not know why ?